# Parse and replace values interchangebly in a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string which has certain "tokens".
Example:

```
"Someone e.g. X here is a # and the other i.e. X is not but over is something else like #"
```

I also have a list of String e.g. `{"John", "doctor", "Jim","engineer"}`

What is the best way to do the following:
I want to replace **all** the `#` characters with the corresponding element in the list.

I.e. I want to skip `X` and `John` and replace `Jim` from `#` and `engineer` for the other `#`.
I thought to just loop over the `string#toCharArray()` but I was interested if there is a better way to do this.

Note: The values in the second list **match** the corresponding tokens. So the first value in the list i.e. `John` maps to the first occurence of `X` or `#` which ever that is.

Example:

Input:  `"Someone e.g. X here is a # and the other i.e. X is not but the other is something else like # but X is at least X but not #"`
         `{"John", "doctor", "Jim","John", "engineer", "doctor"}`
Output:
`"Someone e.g. X here is a doctor and the other i.e. X is not but the other is something else like Jim but X is at least X but not doctor"`

Comment: Your question is impossible to follow. How about just showing us input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested to look at [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) that allows something similar to this kind of replacement.

E.g.

```
MessageFormat.format(""
    + "Someone e.g. {0} here is a {1} and the other i.e. {2} " 
    + "is not but over is something else like {3}", 
    new String [] {"John", "doctor", "Jim","engineer"});
```

**Edit**:

If the input string cannot be modified to include the placeholders and also the placeholders have special meaning as you mentioned in your update (i.e. X should be ignored, # should be replaced), then you just have to

- initialize the counter to 0.
- create an object of `StringBuilder`.
- tokenize the input string on space
- iterate through each token

  - if it is X, increment the counter, append the token as is to the `StringBuilder` object.
  - if it is #, then read the value at index `counter` from the input array and append that to the `StringBuilder` object.
  - append a space.
- `StringBuilder.toString()` and trim to remove the trailing space.

Comment: The string is already in the format I describe.I can not modify it to be as you say

Comment: Having gone through your edit, I updated my reply. Please see the edit.

Comment: Hm.I am not really sure about separating using white space.The strings are much more complicated that the one posted but I get your idea.  
It is similar to what I thought using `toCharArray`. If there is no better answer I will accept this

Comment: toCharArray() would make your logic complex because you don't want to count an X within a word as something to be skipped (e.g.Xylophone). Splitting on space makes sure that if you get a word `X`, it must be a placeholder to be skipped. Same argument applies to '#' as well.

Comment: What if it is in boundaries e.g. after `.;\n` etc?

Comment: Oh! I didn't think the message can span multiple lines. Then char array seems to be the way with complex logic to understand word boundaries. I would also look at `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher` classes, come up with a regex, then go over the matches running the same logic of handling X and # mentioned above.